# Error 500 move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Tenho um problema com o *erro 500*, Ao fazer o Upload de uma imagem na minha página, apesar de concluir o Upload, na hora de mover a imagem para o diretório aparece o seguinte erro:

> PHP Warning: 
>   move_uploaded_file(../../img/produto/221_1157-4f6a306c94af679657ced7273b5ad4ea.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   E:\home\ghpc\Web\v2\controle\upload\upload.php on line 16

Já tentei alterar as permissoes do diretorio
Como proceder?

Comment: Você sabe se o caminho `../../img/produto/221_1157-4f6a306c94af679657ced7273b5ad4ea.jpg` aponta para o arquivo correto? Já tentou usar o caminho completo?

Comment: Tens a resposta no erro que recebeste: `Permission denied` Faltam permissões para aceder à diretoria de forma a escrever na mesma.

Comment: Telefonei na localweb, eles concederam a permissão na pasta para mim agora o código está funcionando como deve. Muito obrigado pelos suportes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se o seu servidor web tem permissões para gravar no diretório "/produto"